# How to clean up unused branch types

Tags: clearcase

I'm trying to reduce access times to ClearCase a bit, and am thinking about removing all the unused branch types (i.e. ones where no element has a branch of that type in the VOB). Is there a simple query that can return unused types, or do I have to scan for instances for each of the existing types?

I prefer something Cleartool or CAL based, as I want to build a tool that can be used by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any "simple query", so it is best to check for each brtype instance in each vob.
First get the list of brtype for a given vob:

```
cleartool lstype -s -kind brtype -inVOB
```

(a bit like in the "[Send to mkbranch script](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html#N104DA)")

Then make a [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) to check if any version of a given element exists for one specific brtype.

```
cleartool find /aVobTag -element "brtype(aBrTypeName)"
```

Note: looking for elements is faster than looking for version here.

If you have the same name of brtype used in multiple branches, the ["Additional examples of the cleartool find command" page](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425) illustrates:

> How to find elements on a specific branch in multiple VOBs:

```
 cleartool find -avobs -element "brtype(branch)" -print
```